# Multithreaded .NET queue problems

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

I'm have a wierd error in my code. It's extremely rare (happens once every few weeks maybe), but it's there and I'm not sure why.

We have 2 threads running, 1 thread gets networked messages and adds them to a Queue like this:

```
DataMessages.Enqueue(new DataMessage(client, msg));
```

Another thread takes messages off this queue and handles them, like this:

```
while (NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Count > 0)
{
    DataMessage message = NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Dequeue();

    switch (message.messageType)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

However once every so often I get a NullReferenceException on the line `switch (message.messageType)` and I can see in the debugger that message is null.

It is not possible that a null value was put onto the queue (see the first bit of code), and these are the only 2 things that use the queue.

Is Queue not thread-safe, could it be that I'm dequeuing at the exact moment that the other thread is enqueuing and this causes the glitch?

Comment: very few things in the .NET BCL are thread-safe in this fashion. In this case, "to guarantee the thread safety of the Queue, all operations must be done through the wrapper returned by the [Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) method". Your problem could also be that two threads are enqueueing or dequeueing simultaneously, if applicable. Either way, thread-safety is your responsibility.

Comment: +1, Good question, it really demonstrates a race condition and its outcome (corrupted/unstable/unexpected situation).

Comment: By the looks of your code, it looks like you're just doing a naive loop for your threads.  You should look into implementing a proper [bounded-buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) to synchronize this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    while (NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Count > 0)
    {
        // once every two weeks a context switch happens to be here.
        DataMessage message = NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Dequeue();

        switch (message.messageType)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

... and when you get that context switch in that location, the result of the first expression
(`NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Count > 0`) is true for both threads, and the one that get's to the `Dequeue()` operation first get's the object and the second thread get's a null (instead of InvalidOperationException because the Queue's internal state wasn't fully updated to throw the right exception).

Now you have two options:

1. Use the .NET 4.0 [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)
2. Refactor your code:

and make it look somehow like this:

```
while(true)
{
  DataMessage message = null;

  lock(NetworkingClient.DataMessages.SyncRoot) {
       if(NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Count > 0) {
          message = NetworkingClient.DataMessages.Dequeue();
       } else {
         break;
       }
    }
    // .. rest of your code
}
```

Edit: updated to reflect Heandel's comment.

Comment: the question does say "Another thread takes messages off this queue and handles them". This would mean a simultaneous dequeue from 2 threads would never happen. #justsaying

Answer (score 11):

> Is Queue not thread-safe, could it be
>   that I'm dequeuing at the exact moment
>   that the other thread is enqueuing and
>   this causes the glitch?

Exactly. `Queue` is not thread-safe. A thread-safe queue is `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`. Use it instead to fix your problem.

Comment: Don’t use `ConcurrentQueue` blindly; only use it if you know what you’re doing. In some situations a `Queue` with locks is a better choice. The concurrent collection classes are not miracle cures for concurrency woes :)

Answer (score 8):

In case you are interested in the exact reason:

`Enqueue` looks like this:

```
this._array[this._tail] = item;
this._tail = (this._tail + 1) % this._array.Length;
this._size++;
this._version++;
```

And `Dequeue` like this:

```
T result = this._array[this._head];
this._array[this._head] = default(T);
this._head = (this._head + 1) % this._array.Length;
this._size--;
this._version++;
```

The race goes like this:

- There is 1 element in a queue (head == tail) so your reader thread starts dequeuing but is interrupted after the first line in `Dequeue`
- Then another element is enqueued and put at position `tail` which is equal to `head` at this point.
- Now `Dequeue` resumes and overwrites the element which was just inserted by `Enqueue` with `default(T)`
- The next time you call dequeue you get the default(T) (in your case null) instead of the actual value

Comment: +1, it's nice to see exactly what is happening behind the scenes. I guess I should be more careful when multithreading! I'm glad I found this bug and it won't make it into the release.